# How long should it take for my Floyd Rose to go back in tune? Also, does the bridge need to be 100% parallel?

Tags: guitar, bridge, tremolo-system

I just started using my new Charvel with a FR 1000 Series; love it! The tuning is epic, until I do a dive; immediately after, my Korg CA-40 says its out of tune. A few mins later, doing nothing, it's back in tune again. What's going on here and is this normal?

Is this normal? Also, it looks like my bridge is at about 1-3 degrees vs the body; as in parallel being 0. Is this OK?

Comment: If you wait about 20 seconds after you do a dive, is the instrument back in tune again? If not, is it more in tune than just after the dive?

Answer (score 1):

A properly set up Floyd Rose type bridge should almost immediately return to in-tune. With a standard set up the bridge is usually parallel or nearly parallel to the body.  It sounds like you need to have a set up done on the bridge to get it aligned correctly, and to check that there isn't anything mechanically wrong with the unit.